# How can I save a file in the phones local storage programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I would be very glad if someone can tell me what I am doing wrong in the code. The folder is not created and it does not show any error.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Button btn;
    Bitmap bitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.image);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.save);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bitmap=viewToBitmap(imageView,imageView.getWidth(),imageView.getHeight());
                FileOutputStream outputStream;
                File sdCard=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File dir=new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()+"/Yourfiles");
                dir.mkdir();
                String filename=(String.format("%d.jpg",System.currentTimeMillis()));
                File outfile=new File(dir,filename);
                try {
                    outputStream=new FileOutputStream(outfile);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,outputStream);

                    outputStream.flush();
                    outputStream.close();
                    Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                    i.setData(Uri.fromFile(outfile));
                    sendBroadcast(i);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }
        });
    }
    private static Bitmap viewToBitmap(View view, int widh, int hight)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(widh,hight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas=new Canvas(bitmap); view.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }

}
```

Comment: "it does not show any error" -- I suspect that it is, in Logcat. You need to request permissions to write to that location in the manifest. On Android 6.0+, you need to request those at runtime as well, and your code is not doing that. On Android 10 and 11, you also need to add another manifest setting to opt into "legacy external storage".

Comment: you can save file without permission to local file storage